# Make NextJS <Link> respect the default "Redirects" middleware

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, nextjs-redirects

I'm using React and NextJS version 12 and want to redirect these two URLs:

- `http://localhost:3000`
- `http://localhost:3000/`

Both should go to

- `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`

I have the following [Redirects middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) set up:

```
async redirects() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/',
      destination: '/dashboard',
      permanent: false,
    },
  ];
},
```

This works if I type either URL above in my address bar. However, this does not work:

```
<Link href="/">dashboard</Link>
```

This will instead send me to the `index.tsx` at the root (a fallback page, just in case we'd ever need it) at the URL `http://localhost:3000`. It should redirect to `http://localhost/dashboard`.

Perhaps I'm confused about what runs on the server versus on the client? I come from Angular where the routes and redirects are for client (or both, when using SSR, I believe).

How do I make the `Link` respect the built in `Redirects` middleware from NextJS? Or is my only option to write custom middleware?

Comment: `redirects` only work for requests made to the server. `next/link` navigation happens on the client-side, thus is not affected by `redirects`. If you need to route to the `/dashboard` route why not just link to it directly, i.e. `<Link href="/dashboard">dashboard</Link>`.

Comment: Ah, that explains things. Shame, I had expected the middleware to support both client and server side. Will have to look for another solution then.

Comment: Good question why not to change the `href`s, I don't want that because then I duplicate in many places what the "default" page of my app is when you go to `/`. I don't want to spread that concern all around my pages and components, if I can help it.

Comment: You could define a `defaultRoute` variable that would be used across the app, and modify it in a single place. You could even reuse it in your `redirects` to keep things consistent.

Comment: Cheers, that sounds like a proper workaround/solution.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to add an `UseEffect` on your `index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Router from "next/router";

const Home = (props: any) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { pathname } = Router;
    if (pathname === "/") {
      Router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  });
  return <></>;
};

export default Home;
```